# Error: Cannot find module 'babel-code-frame' in VUEJS ( ESLINT)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint, package.json, vue-cli

**This is my current version**:

-npm: 6.14.4

-node: v10.19.0

-eslint: v5.0.1

-linux: ubuntu 20.04

**This is my script**:

```
vue create vue1
cd vue1
npm run serve
```

**This is my package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "vue1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    },
    "rules": {}
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not dead"
  ]
}
```

**This is my trace log**:

```
 INFO  Starting development server...
 ERROR  Error: Cannot find module 'babel-code-frame'
Error: Cannot find module 'babel-code-frame'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/eslint/lib/formatters/codeframe.js:8:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at exports.loadModule (/home/logan/Desktop/vue-demo/vue1/node_modules/@vue/cli-shared-utils/lib/module.js:79:14)
    at api.chainWebpack.webpackConfig (/home/logan/Desktop/vue-demo/vue1/node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-eslint/index.js:59:26)
    at webpackChainFns.forEach.fn (/home/logan/Desktop/vue-demo/vue1/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/Service.js:236:40)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! vue1@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the vue1@0.1.0 serve script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/logan/.npm/_logs/2021-04-22T15_06_46_861Z-debug.log
```

I'm also follow this solution in this [link](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/6024), but I dont know exactly how to do because of my poor understanding, I know there's something wrong with my ESLINT at   `at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/eslint/lib/formatters/codeframe.js:8:19)` ...Can you guys give me instruction?
Thank you guys so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you run this command first `npm install` prior to `npm run serve` ?

Comment: Yes, I did it, I also install 'babel-code-frame', but it doesnt work.

Comment: can you look for eslint? Seems like you have it installed against your node_modeuls and that might be a problem too.

Comment: It's already installed by default with vue/cli...hmmm can you explain more? I dont really get your word.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]
I already solved this problem by uninstall npm, nodejs and reinstall them.

```
sudo apt-get remove npm
sudo apt-get remove nodejs

sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
```